# Changing the Google map location via Java code in SWT?

Tags: java, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, swt

I have been following [this](http://www.mkyong.com/google-maps/google-maps-api-hello-world-example/) tutorial for creating a map browser in SWT.

It seems that the map center is set in the html file.
Is there a way to change the location (latitude and longitude values) from the Java code?
I am trying to implement a vehicle tracking system.

thanx in advance.

Comment: If you are using the SWT `Browser` to display the map, then you can easily modify the html/javascript code before you use `browser.setText(html)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do some experimentation with `BrowserFunction` in swt. it is used for callback from java script to java in SWT browser.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround for the problem.
I created a string array with the contents of the Html file and passed it to the browser. Found it in [this snippet.](http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/viewvc.cgi/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet307.java?view=co)

The Contents of the Html code was taken from [this blog.](http://xihuisoft.blogspot.com/2012/02/use-google-map-in-swt.html)